# Creating a new data frame using existing data, by filtering out specific data

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

I'm using the data iris in R.

I'm trying to create a data frame consisting of only the “Sepal.Length”, “Sepal.Width” and “Species” columns for only the rows of species “setosa” and “versicolor”, and assigning the data frame to name “df”.
Species contains 3 different species and I only want 2 types in my new data frame.
Ive tried so many things and Im still lost. Can someone help?

```
library(datasets)
library(dplyr)
data(iris)
summary(iris)
names(iris)

df = iris[,c("Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width")]
dim(df)
            
df = subset(Species, Species== "versicolor")
dim(df)
x = iris$Species == "versicolor"

df <- df[which(iris$Species =="versicolor"& "setosa"  ),]

subset(df, Species %in% c("versicolor", "setosa"))
```

Comment: This row here is wrong: `df = subset(Species, Species== "versicolor")`. You want `df <- subset(df, Species == "versicolor" | Species == "setosa")`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
library(dplyr)
df <- iris %>%
  filter(Species != "virginica") %>%
  select(starts_with("S"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `subset` from base R:

```
subset(iris, Species != "vericolor", startsWith(names(iris), "S"))
```

Or without `subset`:

```
iris[iris$Species != "vericolor", startsWith(names(iris), "S")]
```